# fast_executemany feature for mysql

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using `pandas.to_sql` to insert rows into tables. I read that SQLAlchemy released an option of `fast_executemany` for `mssql+pyodbc` connections. I wanted to know if there is something similar I can use for MySQL?

My current code:

```
dstConn = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(user, pwd, dbServer, PORT, dbName),
echo=False, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)

for items in pd.read_sql(sqlFrom, con = origConn, chunksize = 2000):

        items = items.rename(columns = rename_cols)
        table_name = 'mytable'
        items.reindex(columns = get_dst_colums).to_sql
                   (name = table_name, con = dstConn, if_exists = 'append', index = False, method = None)
```

In pandas official docs for `to_sql` there is another argument called - `method` which is default `None`. I wanted to know if I set that to `Multi` would I receive any speed up for the above inserts?